# Generic Configurable Condition checker at Runtime

Tags: c#, configuration, runtime, expression-trees

I'm writing a "generic" achievement system for my MMORPG project, it needs to be friendly & efficient for my game designers (without having to write any kind of code to add new achievements).

For that, I thought about a solution, which is a basic configuration file that is linked to an enumeration of "eventType" and provide a list of **optional args** (based on the Event properties)
Here is an example

```
name: ACHIEVEMENT_NAME
event_type: ITEM_USAGE # enum as a string, there is a list of event types
count: 30 # 30 item usage
args: # every args are optional
  item_vnum: 1127 # vnum - optional
  map_id: 1 # on map id 1 only - optional
```

```cs
public enum AchievementEventType
{
    ITEM_USED,
    MONSTER_KILLED,
}

public interface IAchievementArgument
{
    AchievementEventType EventType { get;}
}

public class MonsterKilledAchievementArgument : IAchievementArgument
{
    public AchievementEventType EventType => AchievementEventType.MONSTER_KILLED;

    public long MonsterVnum { get; set; }
    public short? MapId { get; set; }
}

public class AchievementConfiguration
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EventType { get; set; }
    public long Count { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object>? Args { get; set; }
}

public delegate bool AchievementFilter(IAchievementArgument achievementArgument);
```

I thought about generating an expression tree to build a delegate (`AchievementFilter`) for my "Achievement incremental condition"
(Basically, the function that will check if the player's specific achievement counter can be incremented or not)

There are two solutions I thought, both have their pros/cons, but I'm looking for external point of view, what do you think about it. (or maybe, another kind of solution that you could present me)

#### 1 expression tree per achievement

I generate 1 expression tree per achievement that will compare the `IAchievementArgument` given as parameter with the achievement configuration.

- Pros :

  - faster at execution time (each achievement condition have their own delegate)
- Cons:

  - Memory footprint

#### 1 expression tree per args type

I generate 1 expression tree per `IAchievementArgument` type that will fetch and compare achievement configuration one by one

- Cons :

  - More execution time (needs to check all key/value equality of each achievement configuration)
- Pros :

  - Lighter memory footprint

Thanks by advance :slight_smile:

Comment: Please, do not share the code as images

Comment: Edited sorry :)